# What are the new features in apache ofbiz branch release 17.12 or 18.12 compared to stable version of 16.11

Tags: ofbiz

After stable version of ofbiz 16.11, ofbiz did two more branch releases, 17.12 and 18.12. What is the new feature this two releases are offering? Is there any guide for this? I searched in there source code readme file but not found any definite answer. If I want to upgrade to these versions what things I need to keep in mind? Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Regards
Koushik

Answer (score 0):

The changes are

https://ofbiz.apache.org/release-notes-17.12.01.html

Because version 18.12 is in development, therefore there has not official information.